# Assigning Group ID to components in networkx

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping, networkx

I have a graph which consists of nodes having "parentid" of hotels and "phone_search" stored in them. 
My main aim to build this graph was to connect all "parentid" which have similar "phone_search" (recursively), eg, if parentid A has phone_search 1,2; B has 2,3; C has 3,4; D has 5,6 and E has 6,7, then A,B, C will be grouped in 1 cluster and D and E in another cluster.

This is my code to build the nework:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient  # To import client for MongoDB
import networkx as nx
import pickle

G = nx.Graph()

#Defining variables
hotels = []
phones = []
allResult = []
finalResult = []

#dictNx = {}

# Initializing MongoDB client
client = MongoClient()

# Connection
db = client.hotel
collection = db.hotelData

for post in collection.find():
    hotels.append(post)

for hotel in hotels:
    try:
        phones = hotel["phone_search"].split("|")
        for phone in phones:
            if phone == '':
                pass
            else:
                G.add_edge(hotel["parentid"],phone)
    except:
        phones = hotel["phone_search"]
        if phone == '':
            pass
        else:
            G.add_edge(hotel["parentid"],phone)

# nx.write_gml(G,"export.gml")
pickle.dump(G, open('/home/justdial/newHotel/graph.txt', 'w'))
```

**What I want to do**: I want to assign a group ID to each component and store it into a dictionary so that I can access them with ease every time directly from the dictionary.

**Example** : Gid 1 will contain some parentids and phone_searches which are in the same cluster. Similarly Gid 2 will contain nodes from another cluster and so on...

I have one more doubt. Is accessing the nodes from dictionary using group ID faster than performing a bfs on networkx graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want basically a list of nodes based on their component (not cluster), which is fairly straightforward. You need [`connected_component_subgraphs()`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.htmlhttp://).

```
G = nx.caveman_graph(3, 4)  # generate example with 3 components of four members each
components = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)

comp_dict = {idx: comp.nodes() for idx, comp in enumerate(components)}
print comp_dict
# {0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6, 7], 2: [8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

In case you want the component IDs as node attributes:

```
attr = {n: comp_id for comp_id, nodes in comp_dict.items() for n in nodes}

nx.set_node_attributes(G, "component", attr)
print G.nodes(data=True)
# [(0, {'component': 0}), (1, {'component': 0}), (2, {'component': 0}), (3, {'component': 0}), (4, {'component': 1}), (5, {'component': 1}), (6, {'component': 1}), (7, {'component': 1}), (8, {'component': 2}), (9, {'component': 2}), (10, {'component': 2}), (11, {'component': 2})]
```

Comment: I just had one more problem. In the graph, as you can see, I have a mixture of "parentid" and "phone_search". But I want to store only the "parentid"s in the dictionary, not the "phone_search". One way to differentiate between them is that all "phone_search" are numbers and **all "parentid"s begin with "P"**.

Comment: Without example I don't fully understand. But I do believe it's a different question. Or is this still about components?

Comment: In a way, it is. In a component, some nodes consist of parentids and some are phone numbers. But when I'm storing the values of nodes in a dictionary, I only want to store the nodes which begin with the letter P (which denote in my database that it's a parentid). So basically, I want to store all the parentid nodes of the components in my dictionary and not the nodes which are phone_search.

Comment: I'll add an example to clear this up. Suppose a component has nodes P1, P2, P3, 1, 2, 3. So when I store this connected component in a dictionary, I only require P1, P2 and P3 to be stored there. It should look like {0: [P1, P2, P3],...}.

Comment: Technically this question is not about components. But still easy: Either you don't add them, or you remove them from the graph (using `remove_nodes_from()`), or you don't add them to the `comp_dict` (by checking for a leading P in the generation of `attr`), or you remove them from the `comp_dict` (by iterating over the values).

Comment: I tried this but it's still not working.
`comp_dict = {for idx, comp in enumerate(components):
    if "P" in comp.nodes:
     idx: comp.nodes()}`

Comment: You should seriously learn about dict comprehension: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Answer (score 0):

**This is a comment due to lack of reputation.**

The "set_node_attributes" functions changed the order of the arguments between v1.x and v2.0 to allow more options for loading attributes.
The order is:  (G, values, name)   instead of (G, name, values)

If using the keyword argument then order is not important:

nx.set_node_attributes(G, name='component', values=attr)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an improvement on the previous and accepted answer, just an update on the correct syntax for getting and setting the component ID as a node attribute within the current version of NetowrkX.

```
##-- Get the components of the graph in descending size order
components = {index:{'nodes':list(comp)} for index,comp in enumerate(list(sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)))}
##-- Create a dictionary of nodeIndex:componentNumber
comp_ids = {n: comp_id for comp_id,nodesDict in components.items() for n in nodesDict['nodes']}
##-- Use that attribute dict to set node attributes in place 
nx.set_node_attributes(G, comp_ids, "component")
```