# Create network based on two columns of a dataframe and add its components ids as a new aggregated column

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table, networkx

In R, I can create a network based on two columns of a dataframe and then assign its cluster membership ids as a new aggregated column to the original dataframe as shown below.

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
g = graph_from_data_frame(df[, .(col1, col2)])
clu = clusters(g)
df[, cluId := clu$membership[as.character(df[, col1])]]
```

How would you do the same operation in Python with pandas and igraph, or networkx?
I found a similar question here but the answer provided is very slow.

[Assigning Group ID to components in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614149/assigning-group-id-to-components-in-networkx)

example:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to create the network from the dataframe? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @ducminh I have edited the question.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. How is the graph related to the dataframe? What do you mean by clusters? Connected components of the graph?

Comment: @ducminh yes, by clusters I mean connected components. Thanks

Comment: But how do you want to construct the graph from the dataframe? Or do you just want to find the connected components of a given graph?

Comment: @ducminh As you can see from form the third line of sample code, I am creating the graphs based on the two column of a dataframe. each row represent an edge in the graph and unique elements in each column are nodes of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

```
import networkx as nx

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(df.itertuples(index=False))

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)

# Find the component id of the nodes
node2id = {}
for cid, component in enumerate(connected_components):
    for node in component:
        node2id[node] = cid
```

Now `node2id` is a dictionary mapping a node to its component's id. You could then generate a column based on this dict and add it to the original dataframe as in [michaelg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547422/9565387).

**Edit**

Better way to obtain the graph from the dataframe:

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I can accept your answer if you complete it with this final line.

df['cluId'] = df['col1'].map(node2id)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### How to assign cluster number to a pandas Dataframe ?

For the demonstration, we will generate a dataframe:

```
def get_letter():
    return random.choice(list(set(string.ascii_letters.upper())))

origin = [get_letter() for i in range(100)]
destination = [get_letter() for i in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'origin':origin, 'destination': destination})
```

### Get the clusters

```
clusters = [random.choice(range(100)) for i in range(100)]
```

### Assign the clusters as a new column of the original dataframe

```
df['cluster'] = clusters
```

[out:]

<kbd>destination</kbd> <kbd>origin</kbd>  <kbd>cluster</kbd> 
<kbd>D</kbd>           <kbd>J</kbd>       <kbd>53</kbd>      
 <kbd>M</kbd>           <kbd>L</kbd>       <kbd>60</kbd>      
 <kbd>K</kbd>           
<kbd>L</kbd>       <kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: In your example, how cluster is related to other two columns?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you are asking about adding a new column to the original dataframe. Here, I just used a random cluster number. Do your question is related to the choice of the clustering algorithm instead?

Comment: all connected components of the first two columns create a cluster. Like the the example provided in the question. Thanks

Comment: I cannot help you reproduce the same result without understanding the clustering algorithm used. Your example doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Every row in dataframe is an edge of the graph and every element from col1, col2 is a node.

Comment: Sure, but how to predict that edge (1, 11) is in cluster 1 and edge (2, 12) is in cluster 2 ?